# If $X_n \nearrow X$, i.e., $X_n \subset X_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup_n X_n = X$, then $\operatorname{int} X_n \nearrow \operatorname{int} X$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X,X_n$ be subsets of a topological space $E$ such that $X_n \nearrow X$, i.e., $X_n \subset X_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup_n X_n = X$. Clearly,
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^n \operatorname{int} X_i = \operatorname{int} X_n =  \operatorname{int} \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i \right ).
$$
I would like to ask if this property extends to countably infinite union, i.e.,
$$
\bigcup_n \operatorname{int} X_n = \operatorname{int} X = \operatorname{int} \left ( \bigcup_n X_n \right ).
$$

Comment: Suppose that $E$ is countable and let the topology $E$ be $\{\emptyset, E\}$ what is the interior of any subset other than $E$? Note that defining $E_n = \{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ we get a sequence with the desired properties.

Comment: @PedroBrunialti You're right. Are there some conditions on the topology of $E$ that make $\operatorname{int} X_n \nearrow \operatorname{int} X$? I hope the result holds at least in case $E = \mathbb R^d$.

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't hold even $R^n$. Let $Q=\{x_n\}$ be any enumeration of the rationals. Now consider $X_n = (R-Q) \cup \{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$. Since between any two irrationals there are an infinite number of rationals each $X_n $ has empty interior.

Comment: @PedroBrunialti Are there some topological properties (such as closeness/openness/convexity) of $X, X_n$ that make $\operatorname{int} X_n \nearrow \operatorname{int} X$ holds?